# Find one in Bolt

Tags: go, boltdb

I have a Golang project and I am using Bolt as my Database. I found and started to use [This project](https://github.com/asdine/storm) to handle the connection and operations over the database. My current problem is that I cannot make a search by one field and get one result.

My struct definition in Golang is:

```
type Component struct {
    ID          int      `storm:"increment"`
    Name        string   `storm:"id,unique"` // primary key
    Cars        []string `storm:"index"`  // this field will be indexed
    Houses      []string `storm:"index"`  // this field will be indexed
    Pets        []string `storm:"index"`  // this field will be indexed
    Children    []string `storm:"index"`  // this field will be indexed
    Level       int
}
```

At first, I know is strange to have one field ID and a field Name with the tag *id*, the thing is that I want the name as the id and possibly as the key. I made some inserts and everything is ok, I even retrieved all the values and it worked perfectly.
Now, I want to get one element by his name, I have this:

```
name := "someComponent"
var component models.Component
err := db.One("Name", name, &component)
```

But it returns `not found` but I know that a component is stored with that name. In other hand, if I make the search with `Find` I get the element, but that command is to return many results, and I want only one, I have this:

```
var components []models.Component
err := db.Find("Name", name, &components)
```

Comment: Just a thought for a workaround: `err = db.Find("Name", name, &components, storm.Limit(1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drafting answer from my comment.

Per library codebase, `ID` is getting in your way even though `Name` is defined as primary key.

If you would like to keep `Name` as primary key, can you please remove the field `ID` from struct `Component` and then try method `db.One`.